# dynamic dictionary using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, dictionary

I am trying to populate dictionary object at client side which i can pass to my Action method. I am able to build the dictionary object with hard coded values however i want to create it dynamically based on the DOM elements.

Here is the how to code looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="t1" class="textClass" />
<input type="text" id="t2" class="textClass" />
<input type="text" id="t3" class="textClass" />
<input type="text" id="t4" class="textClass" />
<input type="text" id="t5" class="textClass" />

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

Here is the JavaScript function with hard coded values. I am looping thru all the text boxes that has `textClass`. This works fine and i am able to see dictionary items in the Action method parameter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.textClass').each(function (index) {
            dictionary = {

                '[0].Key': 'k1', 
                '[0].Value': 'v1',

            };


</script>
```

This is how i want to construct the dictionary but i am not able to figure out how do i use index and DOM element to create dictionary key and value. If i write the way i have written below, it does not construct the dictionary.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('.textClass').each(function (index) {
            dictionary = {

                '[' + index '].Key': $(this).attr('id'), 
                '[' + index '].Value': $(this).val(), 

            };


</script>
```

Can someone please point me what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to construct keys from strings, you'll need to set them accordingly:

```
var dictionary = {};
dictionary['[' + index + '].Key'] = $(this).attr('id');
```

Your currently overwriting the dictionary variable for each iteration. In your scenario, you'd want something like:

```
var dictionary = {};
$('.textClass').each(function (index) {
    dictionary['['+index+'].Key'] = $(this).attr('id');
    dictionary['['+index+'].Value'] = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I had it hardcoded to see if it works or not. Your answer works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.textClass').each(function(index) {

    dictionary = {};
    dictionary['[' + index + '].Key'] = $(this).attr('id');
    dictionary['[' + index + '].Value'] = $(this).val();

});
```